# Diff between two directories with the same file sizes but different file names

Tags: linux, bash, file, directory, diff

I have two directories say D1 & D2. They both contain the same number of files that are of the same size but with different names. Say D1 contains f1, f2 & f3 and D2 contains ff1, ff2 & ff3. 
I wanna do a diff between f1 & ff1, f2 & ff2 and f3 & ff3 in this scenario.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming:**

1. that corresponding files have the same size
2. no two files in the same directory have the same size
3. filenames are simple (no funny symbols like spaces or newlines in the filenames)

Then you can do:

```
ls -1S d1/* d2/* | while read f1; read f2; do echo "diff $f1 vs $f2"; diff "$f1" "$f2"; done
```

Why does this work:

- **`ls -1S d1/* d2/*`:** this creates a list of all files in `d1` and `d2` sorted by size. This means a list where two consecutive files have the same size.
- **`while read f1; read f2; do`:** this reads two entries.

On a simple test, this gave me the following output:

```
diff d1/f3 d2/ff1
1c1
< 11
---
> 12
diff d1/f2 d2/ff2
diff d1/f1 d2/ff3
```

Here, f1 and ff3 were empty, f2 and ff2 identical with 1 character in there, and f3 and ff1 different with 2 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Tricky. Assuming that you are positive that you want to diff files with different names but equal sizes - *this solution will clearly show wrong results if you have more than one file with the same size in source(D1) and target(D2) dirs*.

Try first to get two lists:

```
eval "declare -gA sizes1=( $(find D1 -printf "[%s]=%p\n") )"
eval "declare -gA sizes2=( $(find D2 -printf "[%s]=%p\n") )"
```

Now, iterate over them and perform your `diff`  :

```
for item in ${!sizes1[@]} ; do 
    echo === testing ${sizes1[$item]} against ${sizes2[$item]} =====; 
    diff ${sizes1[$item]} ${sizes2[$item]}; 
done
```

Hope that helps, and points you in the direction you want.